# How to make build fail for warnings from Android Studio Plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following error message being reported in my Gradle output:

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

I know what the issue is and how to fix due to https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java/issues/13

However, I would like to learn more about this warning.

Is this a Gradle warning, javac lint warning or a warning from the Android Gradle plugin?

Also I would like to do is set up my build configuration such that future builds break if this issue happens again. How can I convert this warning to an error?